# Programmatically extract properties from an Azure blob storage connection string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Given a blob storage connection string such as:

> DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=foo;AccountKey=bar;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Is there a known Microsoft object that this can be converted / deserialized into? I don't want to actually parse the string, but I need to extract the AccountName and AccountKey from the entire connection string, which I have as a string.

To pre-empt possible "Why do you want to do this?" questions... I have an existing class that requires the connection string to be injected as a string. To avoid breaking changes, I can't alter that. But I do need to add some methods in this class that need the AccountName and AccountKey as individual items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you install `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common`, you can extract several bits of your connection string programmatically, without parsing the connection string yourself.

For example (with actual info obfuscated):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;

namespace dotnet_connectionstring
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=youraccount;AccountKey=yourkey==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
            Console.WriteLine(storageAccount.BlobEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine(storageAccount.BlobStorageUri);
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine(storageAccount.Credentials.AccountName);
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine(storageAccount.Credentials.ExportBase64EncodedKey());
        }
    }
}
```

This gives output something like:

```
https://youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/
---
Primary = 'https://youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/'; Secondary = 'https://youraccount-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/'
---
youraccount
---
yourkey==
```

Comment: The package `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` is now deprecated. Unfortunately, the replacement package `Azure.Storage.Common` does not seem to have any means of parsing a connection string in the same way.

Comment: I need to extract the account key from the connection string because I need to generate a SAS and this can't happen without a `StorageSharedKeyCredential` which requires an account key. Shame.

Answer (score 5):

There are no classes that I know of that do this, but it wouldn't be that hard to change it into a dictionary. Example below.

```
        string connString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=foo;AccountKey=bar;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

        var connStringArray = connString.Split(';');

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in connStringArray)
        {
            var itemKeyValue = item.Split('=');
            dictionary.Add(itemKeyValue[0], itemKeyValue[1]);
        }
```

Then you could access the values you need using this.

```
dictionary["AccountName"]
dictionary["AccountKey"]
```

Comment: yeah, ok. This is what I was hoping to avoid. But maybe this is the best way.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t even realize you had said that. I really need to start reading these questions better.

Comment: That's pretty much what the libraries are doing anyway - nothing complex.

Comment: You can make this a one-liner like `connString.Split(';').Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(x => x.Split(new[] {'='}, 2)).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1])`

Comment: CAUTION: values can contain a '=' so you shouldn't split with '=' but take a substring till the first occurrence of '=' instead...

Comment: I've made this into a simple utility class [here](https://gist.github.com/seankearon/cae6441bd2789fede6f0ca80a50fd790) (and accounted for the note of caution from @Vince.Bdn)

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @David Makogon is certainly the most elegant but the package `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` is deprecated (as stated in comments). Based on @Patrick Mcvay answer (which is just a bit bugged as there might be '=' in the connection string values), an easy way to parse a connection string would be:

```
var parsedConnectionString = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var item in ConnectionString.Split(';'))
{
    var idx = item.IndexOf('=');
    parsedConnectionString[item.Substring(0, idx)] =
        item.Substring(idx + 1, item.Length - idx - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, we have `CloudStorageAccount` type from `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` assembly.

```
CloudStorageAccount sa = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
```

Comment: I should have said up front that we are using Azur.Storage and not Microsoft.Azure.Storage.  I did see this, but it's in Microsoft.Azure.Storage.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston what about StorageConnectionString?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/44e3a885d76ef753b2dd7bb177639c036c585617/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Common/src/Shared/StorageConnectionString.cs

Comment: @QxQ... hmm. Looks promising. But not available as a nuget?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston this is from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Common/

Comment: @CaseyCrookston can you send me a link that NuGet which you are using?

Comment: StorageConnectionString is internal so can't be used

Comment: @AlanMacdonald good point. I have updated the answer

Comment: Deprecated NuGet package